# The Security To The party [Part 22]

Tags: password

A party is being held at a local mansion. The host is very rich and his success is because of one thing ~ his famous recipe for [Spaghetti!](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Meth)

The only guests that may attend are people the host knows and trusts, whom he gave the password to enter to.

Here's where you come in. You and a friend are trying to steal this recipe. You sneak by and listen to the passwords.

The first guest arrives. The security says "5", and the guest replies "5".

The second guest arrives. The security says "-6", the guest replies "19".

The third guest arrives. The security says "10.5", the guest replies "11".

Your friend thinks he got it all figured out. He approaches the security and as they say "What time do you call this? Your number is -7", when he replies "20" **and he's admitted!!!**

The fourth guest arrives in a cloud of blue smoke obviously late. After apologizing to security for being late he is challenged with "0" and replies "26" and is admitted.

The fifth guest is hot on his heels and arrives. The guard says "Look mate, the letter of the rules here is that you can't come in after 7.00pm but, you are only 3 minutes late so if you get the correct answer then you can come in." and the challenge is "-3" to which the guest replies "16" and is admitted.

Knowing your time has run out you walk up to security, wishing your friend had told you the secret to get in and get "You are going to be the last guest I admit in this zone. 3.5" before the guard quickly changes his mind and asks you for "-9.5" instead, what is the correct response and how do you figure it out?

HINT:

> Look at what the guards are saying. Some of their words are incongruous and will give you a hint on what to focus on. **Note:** I am a fluent English speaker (Australian born and raised), so any weird mangling of phrases is totally intentional and is a clue.

Comment: Is the answer simply 4

Comment: No, of course it's not that simple.

Comment: So, 3.5 is ambiguous?

Comment: @JamesMassey, is the answer not 4 for 3.5?

Comment: @JamesMassey You could put in the question that the guard asks "3.5", but then quickly change his mind because that number is bad and then asks something else.

Comment: negative numbers and decimal places, oh man..

Comment: "What time do you call this?" ...?

Comment: keep that advantage for yourself LOL

Comment: is it 19?.......

Comment: Can't I know how many time passes between each guest arriving?

Comment: A matter of minutes. Its not significant in terms of the puzzle

Comment: Does each guest knows how many people entered before himself?

Comment: No they don't and it wouldn't help you if they did.

Comment: There is a double quote missing somewhere in the paragraph where your friend is admitted.

Comment: Check the hint if you are still stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 22

Some crazy logic

> I think it is related to time..... 0 answers to 26 while -6 answers to 19. If -6 means 6 in evening, it should be 1800 hrs (military), the answer is added with 1 hr more, which can be the reason why 0 becomes 26 instead of 24 hrs (1 hr from each day). -9 means (9+12)= 21 , 0.5 rounds as 1 , so 22?

Comment: I think my logic wobbly...;)

Comment: [Please do not post an answer where all the content is hidden in spoiler markup](https://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1359/should-and-or-are-top-voted-answers-allowed-to-use-spoiler-tags/1424#1424). Your answer should make sense and be distinguishable from another answer to a reader who cannot or chooses not to read the spoiler block.